# what exactly the printWriter() object do in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

```
public class myServlet extends httpservlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(--------"HTML CODE"------);
    }
}
```

I'm new to servlets and web programming. While practicing, I'm stuck at some general doubt. What exactly does the PrintWriter() object do in a servlet? Just directing the HTML code to output stream?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of getWriter? What is unclear about it?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, to handle **I/O operations**, there are different **I/O classes** like **Reader**, **Writer**, **InputStream**, **OutputStream** classes etc. In **Servlet**, when you want to do output operation i.e., writing HTML content in web page, you need one of these classes. More info on these classes, you can get from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) link.

So we create **PrintWriter** instance from the response and invoke its **write**() method to write simple HTML contents.

Comment: My doubt here is, how it is different from normal printf statement ? I'm assuming it directs the html code to run in browser instead of writing it to  console . is that all the thing the PrintWriter() of response object is doing.

Comment: Yes, it handles the formatted content like HTML you write to Servlet response.

Answer (score 1):

getWriter() method of HttpServletResponse returns a PrintWriter object which can be used to send text to client side, and yes it may be used to send html code to the client side.